# Terminal Emacs not receiving <wheel-up> or <wheel-down>?

Tags: scrolling, mouse

From what I understand, I should be able to get mouse scrolling to work in emacs nox mode with the following:

```
(require 'mouse)
(xterm-mouse-mode t)
(mouse-wheel-mode t)

(global-set-key (kbd "<wheel-up>") '(lambda () (interactive) (scroll-up 1)))
(global-set-key (kbd "<wheel-down>") '(lambda () (interactive) (scroll-down 1)))
```

But for some reason I'm not getting the  or  signals. Instead I get this from `C-h k`:

Wheel up:

```
mintty - ESC [ M ` X 1-
xterm  - ESC [ M ` ] &-
```

Wheel down:

```
mintty - ESC [ M a r --
xterm  - ESC [ M a J /-
```

If I scroll down more than once I get this:

```
down-mouse-66-
```

I'm providing examples between mintty and xterm to show that it does not appear to be limited by the terminal. It might be a Cygwin problem but I'm not sure. I AM getting escape sequences but I'm not sure how to map them. They are.. very strange.

Normally I'd used `Ctrl-v` in bash for something like this but obviously it just scrolls the window.

My cursor IS moving when I use the scroll wheel with these settings so it is being detected in some form but it's doing strange things I can't quite describe, like moving up several lines then jumping down again, but this may change with the context. Might there be a problem with mouse.el?

I'm not sure what to do with this.

Comment: How large is your window? Do the sequences vary based on where the mouse is?

Comment: In my experience, feeding the string that I get out of `C-h k` right back into the `kbd` function usually does the right thing.  For example `(kbd "ESC [ M a r --")`

Answer (score 0):

You might use input-decode-map (or function-key-map).

```
(define-key input-decode-map "\033[M'X1-" (kbd "<wheel-up>"))
```

In my linux environment, I could bind normal keybind like C-M-g.
But, not sure about mouse wheel.
(FYI my configuration: https://github.com/yuutayamada/xterm-keybinder-el)

Comment: A nice try but no dice. I tried `input-decode-map` for this and couldn't find a combination that worked. I hadn't tried your suggestion but it only caused junk to be spewed into the buffer when I moved the wheel. I tried different variations of your suggestion as well including `\033[M`X1-` and `\033[M'X1` etc.

Comment: I am pretty sure it depends upon the type of underlying terminal you are using.  For instance in iterm on a mac there are settings under Preferences->Advanced that can change this.  But it would more satisfying it it could be set as wholly in emacs as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Another attempt. (A variant of [yuutayamada's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14552/2642))

```el
(define-key key-translation-map "\033[M'X1-" (kbd "<wheel-up>"))
```